# Any good resorces on quantum field theory in a spherical background?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am considering canonical quantiziation of a free scalar field $\chi$ in a spherical background, which can be spacetime or another scalar background $\varphi$ that couples with $\chi$. In this case, the spatial translation symmetries are lost and one should do the quantization using the spherical polar coordinates. One particular example is the scalar fields in Schwarzschild spacetime. However, I did not find a good textbook which introduce details about how to do the quantization of a scalar field in such a background. Anybody knows of a good material?

Comment: I suppose [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/373527/modern-treatment-of-effective-qft-in-curved-spacetime) would be overkill...

Comment: You may be interested in this paper which computes the free energy for several different QFTs on the d-sphere: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4598

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggested reading for quantum field theory in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110763/168783)